# Using 3 octets (0.0.0) and storing as a variable

Tags: c#, ip, range, subnet

I have an imported excel sheet with 3100 subnets (192.168.1.0/24) as an example. I want to be able to search the first 3 octets with a stored variable. If I can get that, I can edit the spreadsheet to just contain he first 3 octets and get the outcome I would like in the future of the program. Thank you very much in advance.

```
 string octets = ("10.2.30");
        var match = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            IPAddress excelIP;

            if (IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString(), out excelIP))
            {

                if (excelIP.ToString().Equals(octets))
                {
                    match = true;
                    Console.Write(excelIP.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(" -This id was found");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Match ");

        }

        xlWorkbook.Close(); xlApp = null;
    }
```

Comment: 10.2.300 will never match a valid IP, because an octet can't go above 255.

Comment: Oops, I added an extra 0, let me fix that!

Comment: If the cell values are in CIDR format, I don't think `IPAddress.TryParse()` will succeed. You probably need to do `IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.Split('/')[0], out excelIP)`. Then you'll want to use `excelIP.ToString().StartsWith(octets)` since your 3-octet string will never match the 4-octet IP string. Of course then you can have the problem where "192.168.100.1" starts with "192.168.10" so you might get some bad hits there.

Comment: It would have to be `excelIP.ToString().StartsWith(octets + ".")` to make sure the last octet is correct.

Comment: I will give both a try, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Now the thing is, the last octet in each subnet value is a 0, ie 10.2.34.0/24. How would it recognize that?

Comment: It shouldn't matter because the code provided by @BenJ only matches up through the 3rd `.`.

Comment: So if the cell contains 10.2.34.0/16 It will only recognize 10.2.34? I just tried running his with no success. I can set a rule in the excel sheet to remove all the 0/0 out of the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Modify your `octets` string with a trailing period and match it to the beginning of the `excelIP` string.
2. Split the `octets` string into a `List` and compare the elements in that list with the same number of elements of the `excelIP` when split into a list of octets.

In either case, you'll need to add a reference to `System.Linq` to use the expressions.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
```

For #1:

```
// add a trailing '.' so we can match the start of the excelIP
string octets = ("10.2.30."); 
var match = false;

for (int i = 0; i < xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Get the IP address portion of the CIDR string
    var cellString = xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.Split('/')[0];
    IPAddress excelIP;

    // If cellString starts with the octets string and it's a valid IP address...
    if (cellString.StartsWith(octets) && IPAddress.TryParse(cellString, out excelIP))
    {
        match = true;
        Console.Write(excelIP.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(" -This id was found");
    }
}
```

For #2:

```
var match = false;
string octets = ("10.2.30");

string[] octetsToMatch = octets.Split('.');

for (int i = 0; i < xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Get the IP address portion of the CIDR string
    var cellString = xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.Split('/')[0];
    IPAddress excelIP;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(cellString, out excelIP))
    {
        // Compare the first octets of the IP address with our octetsToMatch
        if (octetsToMatch.SequenceEqual(cellString.Split('.').Take(octetsToMatch.Length)))
        {
            match = true;
            Console.Write(excelIP.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(" -This id was found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the 2nd option the "SequenceEqual" doesn't take that argument from the string []

Comment: Yes it does - `SequenceEqual` takes and `IEnumerable`, and `Take` returns an `IEnumerable`. In my example, both `octetsToMatch` and `cellString.Split` are of type `string[]`, so everything should be ok. I updated the question with a small sample of code you can verify with. What error are you getting?

Comment: In the first option  when you get to the Console.Writeline(excelIP.ToString());

It gives me an error excelIP is a use of an unassigned variable.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1928 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments Investigations
 C:\Investigations\Investigations\Program.cs 46 Active


I just tested your code as well. Interesting.

Comment: Oh, well this is `Linq` code, so you need to add a reference to `System.Linq` for it to work. Updated original answer and removed examples since this is most likely the problem.

Comment: I added the Linq reference in already and it still spits me that error...

Comment: Weird. The only usings I have are: `using System; using System.Linq; using System.Net;`

Comment: Mine has an excel sheet linked to it though.

Comment: Maybe the first option is the better route for myself than? Only issue is that ConsoleWrite that I explained above

Comment: To avoid that error, you can always assign excelIP when you declare it.: `IPAddress excelIP = IPAddress.None;` But that part was working in your original example, right?

Comment: I don't know if it was considering I never got any match in the sheet. Should I update my code?

Comment: One of the contracts of an `out` parameter is that it will be assigned when the method finishes, so this statement guarantees that `excelIP` will have a value: `IPAddress.TryParse(cellString, out excelIP)`. As long as your call to `excelIP.ToString()` is inside a block with this as the condition (as we both have in our code), you shouldn't be getting that error. You must be calling `excelIP.ToString()` somewhere else, outside that block?

Comment: Just figured it out, it gets the cell now, prints out exactly the same as my ip. Which is fine for now. Awesome, thanks so much!